# Page auto reload after click on search icon ajax method doesn't hit page auto reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel

I have a search-box when click on the `<a>` it clicks the JavaScript but doesn't hit the ajax method `filter_data_guide_specs()` rather that page auto reloads automatically and further doesn't read the JS

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <input id="search_text_guide_specs" class="typeahead form-control" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="">
  <a href="" id="srchTxt_btn1"><span class="srch-btn fa fa-search"></span></a>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var searchTxt1 = '';
    $('#srchTxt_btn1').on('click',function(e){
        searchTxt1 = $('#search_text_guide_specs').val();

        e.preventDefault();

        filter_data_guide_specs();
        $('#search_text_guide_specs').val(searchTxt1);
    });

    function get_filter_guide_specs(class_name) {  
        var filter = [];
        searchTxt1 = $('#search_text_guide_specs').val();

    });
        return filter
    }

    function filter_data_guide_specs() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{url('guide-specs1')}}",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            },
            data:{searchTxt1:searchTxt1} ,
            success:function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });  
    }
});
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('guide-specs1', 'GuestController@specShare2');
```

`filter_data_guide_specs();` method not hits. on a click `guide-specs1` routre should hit

Comment: your script is filled with syntax errors.. maybe start there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is issue 'Unexpected token' within function 'get_filter_guide_specs'.

```
function get_filter_guide_specs(class_name) {  
        var filter = [];
        searchTxt1 = $('#search_text_guide_specs').val();

   // }); - Remove this Unexpected token. once you remove you ajax will work on click.
        return filter
}
```